# How to pass an argument in an method which in being represented as symbol?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an action as :

```
def get_data
  @people = Person.all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json do
      render :json => {
        :success => true, 
        :people => @people.as_json({
          :only => [:person_name, :text_description, :text_heading],
          :methods => [:title,:age_group],
        })
      }
    end
  end
end
```

Here title and age_group are my methods in model Person

```
def age_group
  self.name
end
```

Now i want to method to look like this

```
def age_group(age)
  # ...      
end
```

How do i pass this argument from the controller as the methods representation there is as symbol.

Comment: I've done some editing so we can read the code, check please if it's correct.

Comment: isn't age an attribute of person? use it in the method.

Answer (score 1):

Hi as per my suggestion you can override method or create a instance method depending upon options it will generate hash or json.If you want to use as_json then you can dig into code this line is helpful for digging code https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2-3-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/serialization.rb#L33 which will give you how methods being passed.

Comment: As per code i tink you can't pas attributes better write some custom method based on that generate hash or json